# a Jensen inequality type inequality problem

Tags: inequality

I was stuck by the following inequality problem for a few days. It is from a high school student.
Assume that $x_i\in (0,1)$, $a_i\in (0,1)$, $i=1,...n$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i=1$. Show that 
$$ \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{a_i}{1+x_i}\le \frac{1}{1+x_1^{a_1}...x_n^{a_n}}. $$
The hint the textbook gives is use Jensen inequality. But I have no idea, since $\frac{1}{1+x}$ is actually concave up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x_i = e^{y_i}$, where $y_i = \log(x_i) < 0$, the required result is

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{i} \frac{1}{1+e^{y_{i}}} \le \frac{1}{1 + e^{a_{1}y_{1}+\cdots+a_{n} y_{n}}}
$$

This can be rewritten as

$$ \sum a_{i} f(y_{i}) \le f\left(\sum a_{i} y_{i}\right) $$

Where $f(y) = \displaystyle\frac{1}{1+e^y} = (1 + e^{y})^{-1}$

This is the opposite of Jensen's inequality, so that if $f$ is concave, it will be true, but one has
$$f^\prime (y) = -e^{y}(1+e^{y})^{-2}
\qquad f^{\prime\prime}(y)= (1+e^y)^{-3}(2 e^{2y}-e^{y}(1+e^{y})) =
(1+e^y)^{-3}e^{y}(e^{y}-1)\le 0$$
Thus, $f$ is concave in $\mathbb{R}^{-}$ and this proves the result.

Comment: Thanks, it is much easier for me to grasp your idea now.